# How to read an OpenSSL cipher suite list

Tags: openssl, starttls, hmailserver

[hMailserver](https://www.hmailserver.com/) is an open source Window e-mail server. For incoming e-mail it supports `STARTTLS` with the help of OpenSSL 1.1.1.
It allows configuring the cipher suites, the default is:

```
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:
kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:
DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:
AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:
AES128:AES256:RC4-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK;
```

I wanted to disable `AES256-GCM-SHA384` but after removing it, the cipher suite was still offered for `STARTTLS` (according to test site https://internet.nl)

In the end I had to remove `AES128`, `AES256` and `HIGH` to stop `AES256-GCM-SHA384` from appearing on `STARTTLS`.

How should I read this OpenSSL configuration setting? On the last line `AES128` en `AES256` are mentioned standalone. Doesn't this mean that *any* cipher with `AES128` or `AES256` will be allowed making the long list before that quite redundant?
The same goes for the `HIGH`, doesn't that make mentioning a lot of the other cipher suites redundant?

Edit:
In response to questions *why* I want to remove `ES256-GCM-SHA384`: for a Dutch government contract they expect our e-mail server to score excellent at the https://internet.nl test site. On `AES256-GCM-SHA384` it tells:

> At least one of your mail servers supports one or more ciphers that have a phase out status, because they are known to be fragile and are at risk of becoming insufficiently secure.

That is why I am trying to disable it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are reading the list correctly.

While there is a large amount of redundancy in your example, I imagine that the purpose of the specific ciphers in the beginning is to establish the order of preference for specific ciphers, regardless if the same cipher ends up being part of one of the [built-in lists of ciphers](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/ciphers.html).

As for why you would want to remove `AES256-GCM-SHA384`, that is rather unclear but maybe not relevant to the question.

Comment: In particular a group like AES256 adds to the end of the list all (non-1.3) suites using AES256 _not already in the list_. As described on the man page you linked.